# Which Black Jack anime most closely follows the manga?

Tags: black-jack

I love the manga, [Black Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Jack_(manga)), by Osamu Tezuka; it is truly a masterpiece.

Well, I want to watch the anime, so I looked it up on Wikipedia. Unfortunately, there are multiple animes, apparently. There is a

- [1993 OVA series](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=525), containing 10 episodes;
- [2001 ONA series](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6193), containing 12 episodes;
- [2004 TV series](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=4408), containing 61 ([*or is it 62?*](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=4408&page=25)) episodes.

Frankly, I'm stumped. I just want to watch the anime adaptation of the manga, and I'm unsure which one is most true to the manga, and I don't feel like watching all 3 of these.

So, which one is most an anime adaptation of the manga?

Comment: Technically the 2004 series has 63/64, if you include the [Special Karte](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/black-jack-the-lost-episodes) episode(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Black Jack 2004 Series so far is the most accurate.

I've read up to Volume 5 in the Manga, and so far (I've seen ALL OF THESE) the 2004 one has more elements of the original story composed by Osamu Tezuka.

What I like especially about the 2004 (& Black Jack 21) is that each episode even shows (in the introduction) the name of the chapters from the original Manga that the Anime is based off of.

If you want to watch something that's most closely related then I recommend the 2004 TV Series.

Although, like any other Anime Adaptation, there are bound to be some changes.

Comment: [Does it have 61 or 62 episodes?](http://marker.to/bVGd9u)

Comment: There are 61 episodes on the Black Jack TV Series, but there are 2 Hidden episodes in the series making it 63 all together for the 2004 Series.

Comment: Black Jack 21 is 17 episodes long and is a continuation of the 2004 series.

Comment: Then there are the Black Jack Specials that fall into place with the 1st Black Jack TV series as well, and those are 4 episodes long.